# Access permissions for hidden subfolder in Shared Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, permissions, administration

How can I - having the Administrator and Marketing Cloud Administrator roles - find a subfolder in Shared Data Extensions folder if the subfolder has no view rights to any child or parent business unit?

I want to be able to change the permissions for that subfolder.

Thank you!